# Read a file that is already open in Word

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-8.1

I'm trying to open and read the contents of a file in a Windows Store app in Windows 8.1. This is working for me without a problem in most cases, but if the file is open in Word 2013 or Excel I get an exception: `UnauthorizedAccessException - Access is denied`

It seems to me that there must be a way to read the file, because the Windows 8 Mail app is able to send the same file, opened in Word, as an email attachment without any problems.

Here's the code I'm using, it's very simple:

```
FileOpenPicker filePicker = new FileOpenPicker();
filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");
IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> storageFiles = await filePicker.PickMultipleFilesAsync();

foreach (StorageFile storageFile in storageFiles)
{
    try
    {
        using (var stream = await storageFile.OpenReadAsync())
        {
        }
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException  e)
    {
        // Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
    }

}
```

I've also tried various permutations of `storageFile.OpenReadAsync()`, such as `OpenStreamForReadAsync`, `OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read)`, `OpenSequentialReadAsync`, and `FileIO.ReadBufferAsync`, all with the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the way to get access to the in-use file is to first copy the file to the local directory, and then open a stream to the new file.

So I ended up first copying the file to the local TemporaryFolder, and then calling OpenReadAsync() on the result of the copy method. Later on, I delete the copy, though this may not be necessary in all cases, as Windows is supposed to occasionally delete the files in TemporaryFolder of its own volition.

```
StorageFile tempFile = await storageFile.CopyAsync(ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder, file.Name, NameCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
using (var stream = await tempFile.OpenReadAsync())
{
    // Do stuff with the stream.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the "share option" when opening file?

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream("FilePath", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
```

The "FileShare.Read" is probably the key. (Without it I believe the default behavior is NOT to allow shared reading of files.)

Comment: I don't think FileStream is available in WinRT?

Comment: Sorry.  (You're right.  FileStream does not appear to exist in WinRT)  When I saw references to Excel and Word in the initial question I headed down the path of more conventional problems with Windows.  (I will see about updating my SO profile to exclude WinRT)